# grub-rescue prompt at booting, boot-repair fails to repair

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub2, boot-loader, 32bit

I have a laptop ASUS, model G551J, with ubuntu 14.04.5 installed (64-bit
architecture). After (naively) running on it a USB live of Lubuntu, 32-bit, the laptop won't boot any more. A grub-rescue prompt turns up with the following error:

```
error:file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
```

I ran a USB live of ubuntu 14.04.5, and executed boot-repair, but it threw an error, with this log:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24279787/

Now I am stuck at the `grub-rescue` prompt. Is it possible at all to fix this or should I reinstall the OS altogether?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that running the usb live of Lubuntu had left the `normal.mod` file in `/boot/grub.bak/i386-pc/`. Knowing this and with the help of the answers to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266874/cant-solve-grub-rescue-problem) I was able to boot from `grub-rescue` prompt. During this process I had to delete a line in `/etc/fstab` created by boot-repair which intended to load a `boot/efi` partition, as boot-repair had asked me to create a small partition for the EFI table. This line was interrupting the boot process with this message:

```
The disk drive /boot/efi is not ready yet or not present
```

boot-repair had also uninstalled `grub-pc` and `grub-pc-bin`, and installed their counterparts `grub-efi`. This was making grub to look for an EFI table when the OS was configured to boot from BIOS. Reversing this situation fixed the problem, and after updating `grub2`now I can boot normally.

Bottom-line: don't use boot-repair.